# I need help doing API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

soo, i were doing a mockup of an android apps and i just placing a value as a text(like print). what i wanted to do is replacing the text with a variable from API of a JSon.

```
class StatsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _temp = NegaraInfo('id');
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildStatCard('total case', '1.81 M', Colors.orange),
                _buildStatCard('death', '105 K', Colors.red),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildStatCard('recovered', '391 K', Colors.green),
                _buildStatCard('Positif', '1.31 M', Colors.lightBlue),
                _buildStatCard('critical', 'N/A', Colors.purple),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

i want to replace the **value** of each number(**1.81M, 105K, 391K,1.31m**) in the code.
i want to create an API to get a data from a [link](https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/)
I been watching a lot of tutorial,most of them make it as a statefull widget and called it on main.dart which is i dont understand.
what i think of a solution is to make a function that will return a case,death, recovered, etc value to a variable[] and then i will call it in the code like print('recovered : ' + variable['recovered'])

a good explaination will do, thanks in advance

PS.
if you open the [**link**](https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/), it will return a lot of data. i want to specific it like (countryurl = link+countryid)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of calling the api in main.dart is because as soon as you start the app, it will fetch all the data you need. If you store it properly in a singleton class then your data is ready to use. You can access it from your widget tree without making any unnecessary api call.

You need some specific data right? So you can add those methods in that singleton file and call them when ever you need.

Let me know if you have any queries..